# Use "#define IDENTIFIER String" to alias in C#?

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

in C++, one can use this expression:

```
#define IDENTIFIER NAME
```

eg. `#define MY_NAME "Gideon"`

Is this similarly possible in C#?

Answer (score 5):

No. `#define` can only be used to define flags to be tested with `#if` (and then only at the start of a file).

Use a constant string instead:

```
const string MY_NAME = "Gideon";
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are completely different things. In `C++` it basically *replaces* the string  `MY_NAME` with *expression*  assigned to it `"Gideon"`.

The same happens in `C#`, in case of canstant expression, but in `C++` you *can* define complete macros(functions) to `MY_NAME` in order to make them run, which is not possible in `C#`

Answer (score -2):

I am not saying you should do it or that it is going to work as you expect, but there is nothing stopping you from trying to use a C preprocessor (e.g. GNU cpp) on your code.